# <input type="date">に入力中の値を取得することは出来ないのでしょうか

Tags: javascript, html, html5

`<input type="date">`で、画面上で年のみ入力した状態で、ボタンイベントを発火した際に、
画面上に入力中の年の情報を取得する方法はありますでしょうか？

具体的には、以下画像の状態で、messageボタンを押下した際に、「2020」という値を取得する方法が知りたい内容です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ブラウザのデバッガにて、`<input type="date">`のデータを参照していますがそれらしき値が見つけられず、
過去質問も参照してみたのですが、探し方が悪かったのか見つけられず、今回質問したところになります。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<script>

function clickdate() {
    const elm = document.querySelector("#date");
    console.log(elm.value); // ←ここで2020を取得したい、valueは年月日すべてが確定した状態でなければ値が取得できない模様
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="date" id="date">

<button onClick="clickdate()">message</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML Living Standard によれば、値が無効な日付である場合、 `value` プロパティの値は**空文字列**となります<sup>[[1]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#date-state-(type%3Ddate))</sup>。このため、無効な日付の値を取得することは**出来ません**。単にそれが無効な値かどうか、などの判定は `ValidityState.badInput` プロパティを用いて行えます<sup>[[2]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#dom-validitystate-badinput)</sup>。

> #### § 4.10.5.1.7 Date state (`type=date`)<sup>[[1]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#date-state-(type%3Ddate))</sup>
>
> The value attribute, if specified and not empty, must have a value that is a valid date string.
>
> The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the element is not a valid date string, then set it to the empty string instead.

解決策として、 `input` 要素の `type` 属性に **`date` ではなく `text` を使用**し、すべてを JavaScript で制御するという方法があります。これは大変な作業ですが、適宜 datepicker 系のライブラリを使用することで負担を軽減出来ます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。type=textを使用し、Javascriptで制御する方向で考えます。